# Instaling device drivers on Fedora 28

Tags: linux, fedora, drivers, system-installation, hardware

Below are my PC specs:
Gigabyte motherboard
Intel Core i5
16GB RAM
1TB HDD

Previously I had Windows 10 installed on my PC. When I installed Windows 10 on my PC, I had to install drivers like: -
Intel Management Engine
Mass Storage 
Display
Sound
Network
PCI Bus
SM Bus

I have now migrated to Fedora 28. Post installation I see that: -
Display works - matches with the resolution on Windows 10
Sound works

I was curious on how to find out any missing drivers for the OS. Is there an App which I can use to find out or which gives me the information for my PC component.

Does NeoFetch work for Fedora? I see it is available for Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: Your question was asked and answered in detail here - https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/128126/installing-device-drivers-on-fedora-28/

Answer (score 0):

*I was curious on how to find out any missing drivers for the OS.*

Sure : you may want to determine what isn't working and then post a question about that specific driver problem.

*Is there an App which I can use to find out or which gives me the information for my PC component.*

NeoFetch seems to fit this need.

*Does NeoFetch work for Fedora?*

Yes.  The home page for NeoFetch indicates that it works for Fedora.  See https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Operating-System-Support

Answer (score 0):

`lspci -k` will show built in hardware and the drivers in use. (Though not all devices shown here need to have a driver listed, such as memory controllers.) If you see hardware on this list that shows no driver and is not working, you can then troubleshoot it specifically.